# Understanding the parameters in Stommel's Two-Box Model (a model of ocean circulation based on temperature and salinity)

Tags: ocean-models

I was redirected here from the mathematics StackExchange

I am trying to wrap my head around Stommel's Two-Box Model of ocean circulation (specifically of the North Atlantic).

The general idea of this model is as follows: [Diagram of Stommel's Two-Box Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn4Gk.png)

$T_1$ is the temperature of box 1 and $T_2$ is the temperature of box 2. Also, $S_1$ is the salinity of box 1, and $S_2$ is the salinity of box 2. In a "normal" state, we have $T_2 > T_1$ since box 2 represents water near the equatorial regions. The $T_1^*, T_2^*, S_1^*$ and $S_2^*$ represent the temperature and salinity of the surrounding basins (see posted image above).

We also set $\rho_1$ as the density of box 1, and $\rho_2$ as the density of box 2. We can calculate the capillary flow $q$ as follows:
$q = k  \frac{(\rho_1 -\rho_2)}{\rho_0}$

$\rho_0$ is the density when $T=T_0$ and $S=S_0$ such that $T_0=\frac{1}{2}(T_1+T_2)$ and $S_0=\frac{1}{2}(S_1+S_2)$.

Then, we can compute the density of each box as:
$\rho = \rho_0 (1 - \alpha (T-T_0) + \beta(S - S_0))$

We can compute the capillary flow as:
$q = k(\alpha(T_2-T_1) + \beta(S_2-S_1))$

Here, we know that, $\alpha = 1.5 * 10^{-4}$ deg $^{-1}$, $\beta = 8*10^{-4}$ psu $^{-1}$, and $k = 1.5*10^{-6}$ s $^{-1}$.

So far, this makes sense. What I am having a hard time wrapping my head around is the second piece of this leading to a system of differential equations ([see attached image showing how the system of differential equations were obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS0UJ.jpg)). How do I find realistic values of c, H, and d? Where would I start? I tried looking at some published papers, which tend to still not give realistic values for these variables. Similarly, I am not sure what typical values of $\rho_0$ and $T_1^{*}$, $T_2^{*}$, $S_1^{*}$, and $S_2^{*}$ should be. This is not for an assignment. I'm just trying to wrap my head around this model.